# Сгруппировать объекты в массиве

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с объектами. Необходимо его
сгруппировать по имени, а значения ключей суммировать,
если имя совпадает. Сделал флаг, который фильтрует повторения.
А вот с тем, как суммировать значения, разобраться не могу.

Дано:

```
[{
    name: 'aaa',
    coin: 30
},
{
    name: 'bbb',
    coin: 32
},
{
    name: 'aaa',
    coin: 20
},
{
    name: 'aaa',
    coin: 50
}]
```

Результат должен быть таким:

```
[{name: 'aaa', coin: 100}, {name: 'bbb', coin: 32}]
```

Мой код:

```
const arr = [{
    name: 'aaa',
    price: 30
},
{
    name: 'bbb',
    price: 32
},
{
    name: 'aaa',
    price: 20
},
{
    name: 'aaa',
    price: 50
}];
const myFunction = (arr) => {
let result = [];

arr.forEach(object => {
    let flag = false;
    result.forEach((objectResult, index) => {
        if (object.name === objectResult.name){
            flag = true;
        }
    });
    if (!flag) result.push(object);
});
return result; }; 
const test = myFunction(arr); console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно так.

Проходимся по массиву при помощи `.reduce()` с начальным аккумулятором в виде пустого объекта. На каждой итерации проверяем, нет ли в нашем аккумуляторе ключа, равного `name`. Если нет, создаём ключ с начальным значением `{ name: name, coin: 0 }`. Проверку и создание можно сократить до одного шага при помощи [`??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). Теперь мы можем плюсовать значения `coin` в этом объекте. В конце нам останется только превратить аккумулятор в массив объектов c сумами при помощи `Object.values()`.

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'aaa',
    coin: 30
},
{
    name: 'bbb',
    coin: 32
},
{
    name: 'aaa',
    coin: 20
},
{
    name: 'aaa',
    coin: 50
}];

const array2 = Object.values(array.reduce(
  (acc, { name, coin }) => {
    acc[name] ??= { name, coin: 0 };
    acc[name].coin += coin;
    return acc;
  },
  {},
));

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: в js нет оператора ??=

Comment: @UlaLa Есть, но он и правда новый: [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)  Можно заменить на присвоение с проверкой условия.

Comment: @InDevX Ок, простите, сейчас постараюсь добавить.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty ну, я то понимаю что тут творится, но для новичка это слишком было :)

Comment: @InDevX Добавил предисловие, надеюсь, стало немного яснее.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty век живи, спасибо не знал! Решение кстати действительно сложным выглядит

Comment: @UlaLa Да, оно спресовано, но для подобных случаев это уже почти набор идиом, которые могут пригодиться)

Answer (score 2):

Код немного попроще. Алгоритм тот же самый, что и у ответа **@vsemozhebuty**

```js
const array = [{
    name: 'aaa',
    coin: 30
  },
  {
    name: 'bbb',
    coin: 32
  },
  {
    name: 'aaa',
    coin: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'aaa',
    coin: 50
  }
];

const resultObject = {};

for (let item of array) {
  const resultValue = resultObject[item.name];
  if (resultValue) {
    // у нас такой уже есть, плюсуем
    resultValue.coin += item.coin;
  } else {
    // такого еще нету - создаем новый
    resultObject[item.name] = { ...item };
  }
}
const resultArray = Object.values(resultObject);

console.log(resultArray);
```